# how do i create a boxshadow underneath my header?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a box shadow for underneath my header similar to the one on the https://github.com/RaghavMangrola/the-brighton-times project-mockup.

I've already tried adding the property and value

> .header {
>         box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
>   }

but I'm unsuccessful in getting the box shadow to appear.
 Could anyone tell me what am i doing wrong? https://gist.github.com/webdevchris/dd10c3e0c585ad94edb0eef793a092c5 Suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank-You! :)

Comment: try !important, especially when using bootstrap

Comment: Do not use !important in this case, it has nothing to do with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your shadow is under your navigation now.

If you remove the background color of .topnav

```
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
   // background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You will see what I mean. Your shadow actually is there, on it's place ( .header class )

May be you would like to use it like that ?

```
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}
```

Comment: IF you really want to see this shadow, try:

`.header {
  color: blue;
  margin-bottom:25px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}`